# Barcode reader javascript

Tags: javascript, barcode

I'm developing an application where I need to read a barcode.

At the moment I'm using the next barcode reader connected on a USB port:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJBro.jpg

The  is catched as keyboard entry

The barcode that I need to read is here (the barcode and the document contains confidential information):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS3aj.jpg

When I try to read the code nothing happens :/, but trying with some diferent barcodes all works perfectly.

I read the next different codes of different length)

OB28018166AB130820635907
BO71133810
SM3924AD1L1
353321066853733
6947681519176
00000000032726960858

Are any way to configure?

All barcode readers can read all barcodes?

Thanks

Comment: Not all barcode readers read all barcodes.  Different businesses set them up differently sometimes.

Comment: Put it this way: if I made a barcode containing confidential information, then I would either encrypt the data, or devise a coding system that other people could not read. If you try my invented barcode system with your reader, it won't read it. Some readers will read the common standards like EAN-13 or 2-of-9, others read a single type only, for example an in-store reader.